# There are some threads that once pulled unraveled/unravel the whole sweater

Tags: word-usage, past-participles

Sentence <1> is from oxforddictionaries.com, which I think is incorrect, the correct sentence according to me is <2>

1> There are some threads that once pulled **unraveled** the whole sweater.

2> There are some threads that once pulled **unravel** the whole sweater.

If 1 is correct, kindly tell me how?

**EDIT:** I am editing this question as I am not getting my confusion resolved.

1> There ***are*** some threads that once pulled **unraveled** the whole sweater.

This sentence according to me should be having '***were***' instead of '***are***', because unraveling of the sweater is already done.

2> There are some threads that once pulled **unravel** the whole sweater.

This sentence informs the reader that in a sweater there are such threads.

Comment: You can understand #1 as a variant of reported speech. "are said to unravel".  Or you could understand "once pulled" as a hypothetical, with backshifting in the result clause to convey something analogous to modal distance: if pulled, *would* cause the sweater to unravel.

Comment: @TRomano I agree, especially "you could understand 'once pulled' as a hypothetical". You should write an answer.

Comment: Since *[ravel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ravel)* means both to entangle and to disentangle, what does *unravel* mean?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct. The "are" in the first sentence simply means that the threads still exist.

Answer (score -1):

Your first sentence is correct

> There are some threads that **once** pulled **unraveled** the whole sweater.

**Once** is being used as a conjunction meaning **at the time of** or **as soon as**.
In your example, both the **pulling** and the **unravelling** occurred in the past.

In reference to the future

> There are some threads that **once** pulled ***(will)*** **unravel** the whole sweater.
>   There are some threads **when** pulled ***(will)*** **unravel** the whole sweater.

talks about the **cause and effect** of pulling certain threads in a hypothetical case